# JavaScriptCore object getting lost

Tags: javascript, ios, ios7, ios8

We have this code in viewDidLoad

```
self.context = [self.webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
self.context[@"Mobile"] = [WebViewJavascriptInterface class];
```

And our class methods from WebViewJavascriptInterface are exposed to our first web page.

When the user navigates to another page, these methods are no longer available.  The "Mobile" object is not present.

Is this because the page changed?  Where should I be placing this code, or what other code do I need to be put in place?  We want these methods/Mobile object available in the web frame for all of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the lines into `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`

Comment: Do I have to use `self.context = [self.webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
` in `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`.  If I want to transfer some auth info, the web front-end developers have to wait the web load finish to run his js methods